# Sts 3.1.0 is giving error with jdk 1.8 version

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, version, sts

I have selected java 8 with STS ide 3.1.0  But after creating the  project it automatically selected java 17 . So by using pom.xml and build path i changed to jdk 1.8 . but now is giving this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:      org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime    (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:473)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
at com.alexa.main.AlexaApplication.main(AlexaApplication.java:10)
```

is this version mismatch error? Please give me version with their supported jdk.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has anything to do with STS. I guess you are trying to create a Spring Boot 3.x and it requires Java 17